# Is it possible to install NVM when I already have installed nodejs 8 on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, nvm

I have installed nodejs 8, I can't run karma tests with angular 1.. As specified on Karma official website `Note: Karma currently works on Node.js 0.10, 0.12.x, 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, and 7.x. See FAQ for more info.`, I guess problem might be in my node version, they recommend to install node via NVM but I already have installed node 8.. is it possible to install nvm and include there my current nodejs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Q:** Can I still install `nvm` when I already got an existing `node` installation?

**A:** Yes.
`nvm` operates by altering your `PATH` environment variable to determine the `node` version your current shell session uses.

For instance when doing `nvm use 6.10.3`, you immediately can see that $PATH is set to;

> PATH=/home/samuelt/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin

`which node` resolves to

> /home/samuelt/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin/node

Since `nvm` always try to set the path of its `node` installation as the first occurrences in `PATH` even if you have 10 other node installation paths in `PATH`, the rest will be ignored once the system has found the `node` binary.

**Q:** Can I include my installed copy of Node as part of the installed node in `nvm`?

**A:** In theory it is possible. But I will say no. To install a particular node version in `nvm` you'll can do `nvm install <version>`

---

### **Update - June, 2022**

With the latest version of `nvm` (tested on v1.1.9), while installing it detects the previously installed Node, and prompts asking `"Node vXX.X.X is already installed. Do you want NVM to control this version?"`

Then based on your preference you can select `Yes` or `No`.