# Can I install nvm after I've already installed node.js

Tags: node.js, nvm

I'm new with node.js and nvm.I'm new to node.js and nvm and I was told that it would be better to use nvm as I can manage different node.js versions more easily.

My OSX: MacOSX Big Sur

Node version: v15.3.0

Question 1: Can I install nvm if node.js is already installed on my Mac? I installed node.js via homebrew.

Question 2: If question 1 does not work, does it make sense to uninstall node.js and use nvm?

Question 3: If Question 2 applies, what is the best way to uninstall node.js?

Question 3: If I uninstall node.js, do I lose terminal settings that I have already saved in my .zshrc file for npm?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439495/is-it-possible-to-install-nvm-when-i-already-have-installed-nodejs-8-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1: Can I install nvm if node.js is already installed on my Mac? I installed node.js via homebrew.

yes, you can. but there is no need to... leverage nvm to install the desired node version that you want. you can set specific node version as the default version across your system by executing

```sh
nvm alias default <node version>
```

just replace `<node version>` with the desired node version of your taste.

> Question 2: If question 1 does not work, does it make sense to uninstall node.js and use nvm?

as mentioned in the answer above, there is no need to uninstall if for both to operate correctly. though, in my opinion just use nvm without installing node directly into your system.

> Question 3: If Question 2 applies, what is the best way to uninstall node.js?

that depends on how you installed node. if you used brew for it, then you can leverage brew to uninstall node by executing

```
brew uninstall node
```

> Question 3: If I uninstall node.js, do I lose terminal settings that I have already saved in my .zshrc file for npm?

if the setting has nothing specific to node which you installed directly, then no. but you should use [`.npmrc` file for general npm configuration](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/npmrc)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using zsh as default terminal shell

is it correct to install nvm with the following command?

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
```

or do I instead have to use

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | zsh
```

Comment: You can't add a question in a the answer section. Try adding the extra details in your questions or if you're answering your question, make it a distinct answer.